# IDLE (Python 3.4.1) on Win 7 - When I press F5 to run, I want it to just auto save my work

Tags: python

I can't find this anywhere! How do I stop it from interrupting my run with "Source Must Be Saved  OK to Save?"

Comment: Are you using Idle?

Comment: I am using IDLE. I'm surprised I didn't mention that!!!

Comment: Under the Windows version, on the General tab, there is an option to disable prompting for Autosave.

Answer (score 1):

That may work in a window, but on a Mac, go to the top of your screen, select IDLE, preferences, Shell/Ed, and under editor preferences, select no prompt.

Comment: This also works on my Windows machine (Options > Configure IDLE > Shell/Ed).

Answer (score 0):

The python program itself has no buttons. I assume that you are instead working in an Integrated Developement Environtment and that this I.D.E. tries to do the following things when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>:

1. Save the information from the IDE to a file (e.g. myfile.ph)
2. Then start python with the file as argument (e.g. `python.exe myfile.py`).

For that to work the file must be somewhere on disk and you want it to be up to date. Hence the 'source must be saved'.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Options` > `Configure IDLE` > `Keys`. Then, create a new key set with `Save as New Custom Key Set`, go to the action `save-window`, click `Get New Keys for Selection` > `Advanced Key Binding Entry` and paste `<Key-F5> <Control-Key-s> <Control-Key-S>`. Apply the changes and this way the key `F5` will automatically save the script when running it.